# Is this RAM compatible with my Sony Vaio E series sve1511AENB laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, sony-vaio

I have 2GB RAM installed into my Sony Vaio E series sve1511AENB laptop and I want to buy a 4GB RAM. but I’m confused are those ram work together?

My existing RAM is: Samsung 2GB DDR3 Memory So-Dimm 204pin 1Rx8 Pc3-10600s 1333mhz M471b5773chs-ch9 1.5v

Link for [more detail](https://www.amazon.in/Samsung-So-Dimm-Pc3-10600s-1333mhz-M471b5773chs-ch9/dp/B00DUG7GTE/ref=sr_1_9?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1507912454&sr=8-9&keywords=laptop+ram+1333):

- **DDR3 RAM**: 1333mhZ
- **Product Dimensions**: 11.9 x 2.8 x 4.8 cm
- **Item model number**: M471B5773CHS-CH9

And I want to buy this RAM: Samsung 4GB DDR3 Memory So-Dimm 204pin M471B5273DH0-CH9 1.5v

Link for [more detail](https://www.amazon.in/samsung-M471B5273DH0-CH9-DDR3-1333MHZ-SO-DIMM/dp/B0051SQYBU/ref=sr_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1507913785&sr=8-2&keywords=samsung+laptop+ram+1333):

- **Brand** samsung
- **Model** M471B5273DH0-CH9
- **Model Year** 2011
- **Item Weight** 18 g
- **Package Dimensions** 8.2 x 4.5 x 0.8 cm
- **Item model number** M471B5273DH0-CH9
- **RAM Size** 4GB
- **Memory Storage Capacity** 4GB
- **Computer Memory Type** DDR3 1333mhz SDRAM
- **Voltage** 1.5 Volts

What do “package dimensions” mean?

Comment: Please check the technical documentation for your laptop for the specific requirements for compatible memory.

Comment: please tell me what are those two 'Package Dimensions' means? are those two RAMs fit into my Laptop?

Comment: I'd guess that's the size of the package the memory is packaged in. The size of the memory that you care about are the specification "SO-DIMM", the number of pins, and the category "DDR3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your laptop can support up to 8Gb of RAM. This would be 2x4GB memory modules.

You want to add 4GB to your existing 2GB. Yes, both modules are compatible and will work together.

It is better to pair your memory up though. So the best performance would be to remove the 2GB module and add 2x4GB matching modules.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have another question, what will happen if that two ram has different CAS latency? is it possible to have different CL in same frequency(both 1333mhz) of ram(2GB vs 4GB)?

Comment: @AradhanaSen Yes, but you should try to match your two memory modules. The motherboard will operate at the fastest speed of your slowest memory module. So pairing up two identical 4GB memory modules would be best. Any DDR3 (1333Mhz, 1.5v) SoDIMM should work fine.

Comment: is it possible to have different CL in same frequency(both 1333mhz) of ram(2GB vs 4GB)?